# Can you get rid of the install or try screen?

Tags: system-installation

I am using ubuntu on a flash drive, so I can use any computer with it. Although, I found, to my annoyance, that every time I completely rebooted a computer, or booted it on a new one, it asked me if I wanted to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install along your original Operating System". Is there a way to get rid of this screen so it doesn't show again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have Ubuntu installed to your flash drive, not use it as a live disc. First, you're going to want to back up your files. You can [install Ubuntu to the flash drive like a normal hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator), then restore your files from your backup. I am not sure if this would allow you to switch between computers or not, but in theory the generic drivers should allow it.